# Powershell Script to rename multiple folders

Tags: powershell

How do i rename multiple folders, for example "Test", "Folder" and "Documets" as following "Old-Test", "Old-Folder" and "Old-Documets" and so on
I used the below to do that, but i can do it for single folder at present. so i need to do it for multiple folders and is it possible to get output in txt.

Rename-Item -Path D:\temp\Test D:\temp\Old-Test

Comment: Take a look at [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2), [about_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2), [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) and [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Test','Folder','Documents' | ForEach-Object {$newname=Join-Path $_.Parent.FullName "OLD-$($_.Name)"; Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname; Write-Output "$($_.FullName) to $newname" } | Out-File log.txt -Append
```